# Close votes on "review first questions"

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

When I get questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952228/problem-with-calling-and-running-functions-in-class-in-cpp) in the "first questions" review queue, what am I supposed to do?

The question had already been answered by the author in the post's comments and it was a simple solution due to a typo in their code.

I do not have enough reputation to vote for a close, and I do not want to downvote and click "Other Action" because that costs me reputation which, again, I do not have a lot of.

Comment: (I have little experience with using the FQ queue with not enough rep to close vote) Can you not flag to close? The fact that it was a typo is the prevalent thing here, not that it was answered.

Comment: This is answered in our FAQ [What is a "closed" or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-duplicate-question), section *What if I don't have enough reputation to cast close votes, but believe a question should be closed?*

Comment: Did you find: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-the-late-answers-and-first-questions-answers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you can't vote to close, you can *flag* as 'Needs improvement' - that will put the question in the Close Votes review queue if it isn't already there, and other users with enough reputation can close it.

> I do not want to downvote and click "Other Action" because that costs me reputation

Downvoting questions does not cost reputation, only downvoting answers does.